# Upgrade nodejs project version to 7 or higher

Tags: node.js, npm

I have an old project written in Nodejs and Angular and now I'm taking it back.
The problem I have is that when I do `npm install` to install the dependencies of the `package.json` file, I get **"The package-lock.json was created with an old version of npm".**

I understand that this means, as indicated in the message, that I have to upgrade the project version to version 7 or higher.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUQoO.png)

But how can I update the project version?

My NPM version is: **6.14.15**

My Node version is: **v14.18.1**

Also, when I start to deploy the project, nothing happen. Is silent here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtsBL.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem deleting package-lock.json file. It will be re created on next npm install.

To list outdated packages:

```
npm outdated
```

To update a package:

```
npm update <package name>
```

Comment: I deleted ```package-lock.json``` and I typed ```npm install``` but still without work. And when I update my packages with ```npm update <package name>``` but appear me as "up to date". And when I hit ```node app.js``` gets stuck and does not move forward.

Comment: Can you provide an error message?

Comment: I can't get any error, is just that when I run ```node app.js```, gets stuck and does not move forward :(

Comment: Ok, but maybe it's normal?
What is this node.js script supposed to do?
Maybe he is waiting for an action from you?